# How do I know if an app on my phone makes use of App Bundles?

Tags: applications

App bundles (or I believe it is because of them) are screwing me over with regards to Titanium backup since restore simply does not work with those - they are stuck on "restoring". Currently, I only have TiBu on old hardware where it takes very long to do stuff, and if it just says "restoring" I've no idea if it's actually doing anything. More apps will soon adopt this new feature and I want to be able to filter them out easily without wasting too much time.

Is there an ADB command maybe that can tell, or some other way with root?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an app called Split APKs Installer to help.

Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aefyr.sai

Comment: Why the downvote lol

Comment: Hi, I'm not the downvoter, but when suggesting an app, ideally its description and usage is also mentioned on the answer to also help future readers.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what's the exact use case for it. But it helped me solve my problem of knowing which apps on my device are split APKs, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯